# boost read_some function lost data

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I'm implementing a tcp server with boost asio library.
In the server, I use asio::async_read_some to get data, and use asio::write to write data. The server code is something like that.

```
std::array<char, kBufferSize> buffer_;
std::string ProcessMessage(const std::string& s) {
   if (s == "msg1") return "resp1";
   if (s == "msg2") return "resp2";
   return "";
}
void HandleRead(const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t size) {
  std::string message(buffer_.data(), size);
  std::string resp = ProcessMessage(message);
  if (!resp.empty()) {
    asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message), WriteCallback);
  }
  socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_));
}
```

Then I write a client to test the server, the code is something like

```
void MessageCallback(const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t size) {
   std::cout << string(buffer_.data(), size) << std::endl;
}
//Init socket
asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer("msg1"));
socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_), MessageCallback);
// Or async_read
//socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_), MessageCallback);
asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer("msg1"));
socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_), MessageCallback);
// Or async_read
//socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_), MessageCallback);
```

If I run the client, the code will be waiting at second read_some, and output is:`resp1`.

If I remove the first read_some, the ouput is `resp1resp2`, that means the server done the right thing.

It seems the first read_some **EAT** the second response but don't give the response to MessageCallback function.

I've read the quesion at [What is a message boundary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563563/what-is-a-message-boundary/9563694#9563694), I think if this problem is a "Message Boundary" problem, the second read_some should print something as the first read_some only get part of stream from the tcp socket.

How can I solve this problem?

UPDATE:
I've try to change the size of client buffer to 4, that output will be:

```
resp
resp
```

It seems the read_some function will do a little more than read from the socket, I'll read the boost code to find out is that true.

Comment: Could it be a [TCP message boundary issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9563694/478288)?

Comment: @chrisaycock I've read the question you mentioned and update the question, I think if this is a message boundary issue, either the first read_some will get the whole "resp1resp2" or the second read_some should get something from the socket, am I right?

Comment: What is `asio::read_some`? I don't see such a free-function in Asio documentation. Could you correct your question so that it would reflect more precisely what you're doing?

Comment: [`async_read_some()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html) is a member function and not a [free function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html). The code in this question does not make sense as `asio::async_read_some()` won't compile.

Comment: @sam-miller, sorry, I mean use socket.async_read_some function, and make a mistake while I asking the question, I've updated the question.

Comment: @IgorR. I've update the code in the question.

Comment: I can't see the whole picture, but there're 2 common error-prone  points: ensure that you never have 2 simultaneous `async_read`s or `async_write`s in progress; ensure that the buffers outlive the async.operations (`buffer` free-function doesn't copy the underlying buffer).

Comment: @IgorR. I've try to replace the async_read_some to read_some to make the read operation serial, that problem still exist.

Answer (score 2):

The [`async_read_some()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html) member function is very likely not doing what you intend, pay special attention to the Remarks section of the documentation

> The read operation may not read all of the requested number of bytes.
>   Consider using the [`async_read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) function if you need to ensure that the
>   requested amount of data is read before the asynchronous operation
>   completes.

Note that `async_read()` free function does offer the guarantee that you are looking for

> This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the
>   stream's `async_read_some` function, and is known as a composed
>   operation. The program must ensure that the stream performs no other
>   read operations (such as `async_read`, the stream's `async_read_some`
>   function, or any other composed operations that perform reads) until
>   this operation completes.