# Screen-sharing in C# Windows Form using TCP: half screen glitched out

Tags: c#, tcp, windows-forms-designer, screensharing

I'm trying to write a very simple Screen-sharing code in C# over LAN. It seems to be working well and smoothly with a 100s delay besides the screen being cut in half (or at times 30% when I switch over to other applications eg: switching from viewing VS studio to Chrome). What could be the reason?

I've tried it on my 2  laptops as well as tried to share it on the same laptop but the problem persists. Changing the resolution or delay doesn't change anything. I've also tried to save the images locally as they are sent and then looked at them, and they are being saved fully, so there's not a problem with how they're being captured. I'm very confused.

Here is a screenshot of what is happening:
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPr6F.png)]
[sreenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwjVc.png)

Here is how I am receiving the data sent:
[receiving data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODm5Q.png)
And here is how I am sending it:
[sending data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsUGD.png)
Any help is greatly appreciated. This is my first time asking a question here, so I apologize if the format is not according to how it should be.

Comment: [Please don't use images for code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Include your C# snippets into your question.

Comment: This seems like an instance of the classic [TCP does not preserve message boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9563563/21105992) issue. Try adding some prints that verify the amounts of data sent versus received.

Comment: @teapot418 It kept saying that there was indentation issues and wouldn't let me :(
I changed from TCP to UDP and it works as intended now. I think my friend tried to verify and even implemented a checksum in the code to match the data and datasize sent and recieved and it said everything was fine. We're just going to use UDP now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can use TCP, but you have to send the other side some indication inside your protocol how much data is coming and then read it in a loop on the receiving end. TCP will give you the same data you sent in the same order, just not in one chunk.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.